# How to autosave a mode parameters during training neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, parameter

I am still new to python and NN. As NNs trainings is done for example 500 epochs, how I can auto-save the model so that if my connection gets lost or ran out of google GPU, next time I do not start training from the first step. Lets say my model name is **U-NET**. How to auto-save the last epoch's model parameters and also how to recall it? Can someone write the exact code for them in Pytorch, please?

Comment: You can save checkpoint after some steps later or epoch later. Follow this blog: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html